# Nodejs v0.8.20 with mongoosejs for nodejs for fetch query error with no response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I used nodejs 0.8.20 with mongoosejs for nodejs for fetch query. First time it will fetch query with data result. But for the next time with same query doesn't get any response or error messages. It will show always blank.

Please let me know, if i did anything wrong with this code.

This is the code.

```
var schema_reviews =  {
"approved"      :"Number",
"comment"       :"String",
"item_id"       :"Number",
"timestamp"     :"Number",
"user_id"       :"Number",
"user_type"     :"String",
"username"      :"String"}

var reviews_schema      = new mongoose.Schema(schema_reviews);
var itemid = 54;
var reviews_model = db.model('reviews',reviews_schema);
reviews_model
.find({ 'item_id': itemid },function(err,review_lists){
    socket.emit('reponse_reviews',review_lists);
});
```

Comment: I dont' see anything wrong with this particular snippet. Would you ming adding context? (i.e. is this the function you are calling twice, where are you calling it second time etc.)?

Comment: No, calling one at a time. Possibility is, I have tired to access this  function by clicking on same event twice with time limit.